# Taking a list of tuples and returning a tuple

Tags: haskell

I am writing a recursive function in Haskell that takes a list of tuples as input and returns one tuple. The first part of the tuple that is being returned should be the number of tuples that were in the list, and the second part of the tuple returned should be all of the elements from every tuple in the list. To clear it up here is what an example run should look like:

```
gather [ (0, [true, true] ), (1, [true, false] ), (2, [false, true]) ]
  returns (3, [true, true, true, false, false, true] )
```

I am fairly new to Haskell but here is my attempt of the recursive code:

```
gather  [()] = [()]
gather n as = head as : gather n (take n as)
tupList :: [(a)] -> [(a)]
tupList n xs = map (\x -> gather n (take x xs)) [n..]
```

The compiler does not like this at all, any suggestions on what I can do to fix this? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Please, add a detailed error message.

Comment: This is the error that I am getting but I figured out my first problem, I cannot match n with [a]                                                                         Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘[a]’
    Relevant bindings include
      n :: [a] (bound at HaskStuff3.hs:48:9)
      tupList :: [a] -> [a] (bound at HaskStuff3.hs:48:1)
    In the expression: n
    In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘[n .. ]’                                                                                                                             @kraskevich

Comment: and it should be something like: gather [( )] = ( ) instead..

Comment: Unit (`()`) is _not_ a tuple! Tuples are _not_ lists! They have a _fixed number of items, and have types like `(1,True,"3",LT) :: (Int, Bool, String, Ordering)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's a recursive version. it performs only one pass along the input list. doing two independent passes often causes space leaks.

```
gather xs = g 0 xs 
  where
  g c []         = (c, [])
  g c ((_,ys):r) = (a, ys ++ b) 
                     where 
                     (a,b) = c `seq` g (c+1) r
```

`seq` causes the immediate calculation of a counter as we advance along the list. Without it the calculation of `c+1` might be delayed unnecessarily.

This is *guarded* recursion, actually.

Answer (score 1):

First let me get you a working version (I hope this is not homework):

```
gather :: [(a,[b])] -> (Int, [b])
gather xs = (length xs, concatMap snd xs)
```

now to your version:

first you gave no signature but the two cases for `gather` already differ in the number of arguments (the first one would have type `[()] -> [()]`, the second something like `Int -> [a] -> [a]` (what you really want is what I gave - or so I guess based on your example).

The next think is that I don't know what you are trying to do with `gather` - if you explain your thinking I will try to get you on track.

For what you need `tupList` I have no clue.

### remark

I *know* that you wanted a *recursive* function - but this is only preferable IMO if this **is** homework ... so I am feeling not guilty of not giving you a recursive version ... if you want you can just rewrite the `concatMap` part (or `length`) using recursion.

### based on your comment

I think you wanted to do the right think: split the problem into two parts: concatenating the lists and counting the items.

Counting the items is rather simple: either you use `length` or you redefine it:

```
length :: [a] -> Int
length [] = 0
length (_:tl) = 1 + length tl
```

The first problem should look something like this:

```
concat :: [[a]] -> [a]
concat [] = []
concat (xs:xss) = undefined
```

maybe you can try and fill this out yourself (it's most likely ok for you to use `(++)`)

Having both you can just do as I did if you rewrite it into:

```
gather ts = (length ts, concat (map snd ts))
```

### straight from GHCi : your example

```
λ> gather [(0, [True, True] ), (1, [True, False] ), (2, [False, True])]
(3,[True,True,True,False,False,True])
```

Comment: No we are not on Haskell yet, I am looking up exercises and trying to extend my knowledge on tuples and recursion to get a head start. My reasoning behind gather was to take every element through the list and to put it in the second position of the tuple returned. My tuplist I wanted to count how many tuples were in the list and add them to the first element of the tuple returned. Hope this clears up what my thought process was?

Comment: And I just attempted your code and it gave me a not in scope error for every true and false in each tuple.

Comment: @kbelt721 true and false should be True and False.

Comment: @kbelt721 no offense: but it's not my fault if you mistype your own example ;)

Comment: @CarstenKönig ahh I apologize, that is how the website had the example listed with lowercase! It does work perfectly actually.